# Trying to create a control template that inherits parent class and calls?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make a template for a form on my Xamarin.Forms project.
I want to use a SyncFusion `SfCarousel` control, and since I reuse it on a number of forms, I would like to make a xaml view that I can just instantiate on the target form saving from having to recreate the control every time.

Here is the problem, I have `TapGestureRecognizer.OnTapped` and several other Data objects that get passed to this control.
Here are the samples of how it gets implemented as this time.

```
....
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CarouselitemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                            Tapped="OnTapped" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Image
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        HeightRequest="350"
                        Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource Key=FillImageFromBytes}}"
                        WidthRequest="325" />
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

....
                            <Label Text="Images" />
                            <syncfusion:SfCarousel x:Name="carousel" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Key=CarouselitemTemplate}" />

....
```

What I would like to do is this.
TemplateCarouselView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<syncfusion:SfCarousel
    x:Class="BoomStick.Views.TemplateCarouselView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms">
    <syncfusion:SfCarousel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                        Tapped="{Binding Path=OnTapped}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    HeightRequest="350"
                    Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource Key=FillImageFromBytes}}"
                    WidthRequest="325" />
                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:SfCarousel.ItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:SfCarousel
```

TemplateCarouselView.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BoomStick.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TemplateCarouselView : SfCarousel
    {
        public TemplateCarouselView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty OnTappedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OnTapped), typeof(Command), typeof(Command));

        public Command OnTapped
        {
            get
            {
                return (Command)GetValue(OnTappedProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(OnTappedProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I figured I could use the `BindableProperty` to allow the calling instance to add it's own pointer to the Tap Callback function.
I could then implement this view like so.

```
<myviews:TemplateCarouselView OnTapped="SomeFunction" />
```

The problems I have are thus.

1. Can this implementation inherit the `ViewModel` within the template? or do I need to create `BindableProperty` elements for each then `Value="{Binding Path=xxx}"`.
2. The implementation for the `OnTapped` is not handing off to the `TapGestureRecognizer` I cannot figure out how to overload the incoming property to be accepted by the xaml implementation.
3. Each instance that implements this View needs to have it's own overloaded `OnTapped` function, so I cannot just make it an internal call within the TemplateView.
4. Can I make this template use it's own internal `ViewModel` while still being able to inherit the parent forms `ViewModel`?

Thank you for any ideas or pointers!

Cheers!
Jesse

Comment: From what I can tell you cannot bind to the `Tapped` event. Does anyone have an idea how to overload this function so I can bind to it? it seems to be my only remaining hangup for finishing this

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working!
Here is how I went about it, If anyone has any better methods or ways to accomplish this I'd love to hear it!

Here is the template class I had to make

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using BoomStick.Models;
using BoomStick.Services;

using Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BoomStick.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TemplateCarouselView : SfCarousel
    {
        public DataTemplate dt;

        public TemplateCarouselView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dt = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var keyLayout = new StackLayout();

                var bindPhoto = new Binding()
                {
                    Converter = new FillImageFromBytes(),
                    Path = "Image"
                };

                var bindTapped = new Binding()
                {
                    Path = "OnTapped"
                };

                var bindLocalPath = new Binding()
                {
                    Converter = new FillImageFromBytes(),
                    Path = "."
                };

                var tgRec = new TapGestureRecognizer()
                {
                    CommandParameter = bindLocalPath,
                    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
                };

                tgRec.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
                {
                    var act = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(
                                        StringTools.GetStringResource("szPhotoOptions"),
                                        null,
                                        StringTools.GetStringResource("szOK"),
                                        ActionList.ToArray());
                    await TapHandler.ImageTapHandler((Photos)((TappedEventArgs)e).Parameter, act, KeyButton, ParentObject);
                };

                tgRec.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, bindTapped);
                tgRec.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
                keyLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgRec);

                var img = new Image()
                {
                    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                    HeightRequest = 350,
                    WidthRequest = 250,
                };
                img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, bindPhoto);
                var lblFileName = new Label()
                {
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                };
                lblFileName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "FileName");
                keyLayout.Children.Add(img);
                keyLayout.Children.Add(lblFileName);

                return new ViewCell { View = keyLayout };
            });

            Carousel.ItemTemplate = dt;
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ActionListProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ActionList), typeof(List<string>), typeof(List<string>));

        public List<string> ActionList
        {
            get
            {
                return (List<string>)GetValue(ParentObjectProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(ParentObjectProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ParentObjectProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ParentObject), typeof(Object), typeof(Object));

        public Object ParentObject
        {
            get
            {
                return (Object)GetValue(ParentObjectProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(ParentObjectProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty KeyButtonProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(KeyButton), typeof(ImageButton), typeof(ImageButton));

        public ImageButton KeyButton
        {
            get
            {
                return (ImageButton)GetValue(KeyButtonProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(KeyButtonProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can then instantiate it like this

```
<core:TemplateCarouselView
                    x:Name="carousel"
                    ActionList="{Binding Path=ActionList}"
                    KeyButton="{x:Reference KeyImageButton}"
                    ParentObject="{Binding Path=MyClass}" />
```

It took some time, and I couldn't have done it without some help!

Cheers!